# How to sum the numbers included in a letter-number sequence?

Tags: java, for-loop, netbeans, substring, equals

i need to do a program in java (netbeans) where the user inserts any sequence that includes letters and numbers (example: aa5bgd6dcx78), then i need to sum the numbers, like 5+6+7+8 and print the result. Any idea on how i can do this?

I need to user for, substring and equals.

Thank you

Comment: Did you already write some code?

Comment: Try regex to remove letters and substring to get each number then sum

Comment: Yes , i have String x = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write your sequence")
String o = x.substring();

Comment: Since you don't consider `78` to be the number `78` but two *digits* `7 + 8`, you should just iterate the characters of the string and add the characters that are digits. Try that, and if you still have trouble, post the code and we'll help you.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! i´ll let you know if i have any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "aa5bgd6dcx78";

int total = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    curChar = input.charAt(i);
    if(curChar.isDigit()) {
        total += curChar;
    }
}

System.out.println("Total is: " + total);
```